# How to restrict one CPU core per one BPF code

Tags: kernel, c, bpfilter

I am trying to attach BPF at XDP hook points for each NIC on my system ( I have 3 NICs).

I was successful in reducing the number of CPUs from 8 to 3 using `maxcpus=3` as a boot parameter in `/etc/default/grub` file.

What I need is to restrict one CPU to one BPF code.

Any Ideas/Discussions are appreciated.

[image: BPF overview picture]
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For all my affinity needs I use "schedtool"
IE:

schedtool -R -p 90 -a 0xf $$

starts prompt to run the next command at "round robin" "90/100 priority" on 1,2,3,4

but you have to re-execute whatever within that.

Comment: I use a C program to attach BPF code to NIC, so this pice of code would make that C program to run in `round robin 90/100` priority, but what i want is to run the BPF code (part of kernel hook (i think)) on 1 CPU, basically to reduce L1, L2 cache misses. Anyway thanks for the input.

Comment: So you want to boot on 3 leaving the rest free

Comment: @Tradis Guy, I want to boot using 8 cores, but run BPF code on 3 cores

Comment: would the isolcpus variable help? But you would have to script taskset to init your code on the ignored cores...